# jquery to remove duplicate links

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery to remove duplicate links but it remove links from the entire page. I need to target a specific div. I just need to remove duplicate A from nav-report-category

```js
var seen = {};
$('a').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-report-category">
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=">Other</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Inventory">Inventory</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Manufacturing">Manufacturing</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Metrics">Metrics</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Operational">Operational</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Planning">Planning</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Procurement">Procurement</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Sales Order">Sales Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=">Other</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, please use the right selector:

```js
var seen = {};
$('.nav-report-category a').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-report-category">
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=">Other</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Inventory">Inventory</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Manufacturing">Manufacturing</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Metrics">Metrics</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Operational">Operational</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Planning">Planning</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Procurement">Procurement</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Sales Order">Sales Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, you cannot have `<li>` directly inside a `<div>`. Since you have everything in `<li>`, I suggest you remove the whole tag:

```js
var seen = {};
$('.nav-report-category a').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-report-category">
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=">Other</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Inventory">Inventory</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Manufacturing">Manufacturing</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Metrics">Metrics</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Operational">Operational</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Planning">Planning</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Procurement">Procurement</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=Sales Order">Sales Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/Pages/test2.aspx?BF=supply%20chain&amp;RC=">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked for me. var seen = {};
$('.nav-report-category a').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});

Comment: Why would  using a more specific selector fix this? that makes no sense. `$('a')` should have found these anchor tags too.

Comment: @KevinB That was the question dude: **`I need to target a specific div. I just need to remove duplicate A from nav-report-category`**

Comment: No, there's a dupe for that.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, but it's a distant dupe. Okay, thanks anyways...